# Relation between height of peaks of DFT and (continuous) FT

Tags: fft

Even in the simple case of doing the FFT of a simple harmonic $\lambda \sin(t)$ I am struggling to obtain the value of $\lambda$ from the FFT data. My code is

```
T = 100.
N = 300
t = np.linspace(-T, T, N)
y = 2.*np.sin(t)
y_ft = scipy.fft.rfft(y)
frq = scipy.fft.rfftfreq(N, 2*T/N)
plt.plot(frq, np.abs(y_ft))
plt.show()
```

The figure I get is this one:

[image]

How can I see that in this case $\lambda = 2$? What should I do in the case $\lambda <0$?
Thanks a lot!
ps: I know that there are some other similar questions on this site, but I could not find my solution an any of them. Thanks for the understanding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things happening here: DFT scaling conventions and spectral leakage.

The DFT can be defined as

$$X[k] = \frac{1}{K} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j2\pi\frac{kn}{N}} \leftrightarrow  x[n] = \frac{K}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] e^{j2\pi\frac{nk}{N}} $$

where $K$ is a somewhat arbitrary scaling factor. The most common convention is $K=1$ but you can also find $K=\sqrt{N}$, $K=N/2$ or $K=N$ all of which different pros and cons. To preserve the amplitude of a single complex exponential, we need to choose $K=N$ which is obvious from the inverse definition.

Your signal $x(t)$ can be written as

$$x(t) = 2\sin(\omega t) = 2\left(\frac{1}{2j}(e^{j\omega t}-e^{-j\omega t})\right)= -j(e^{j\omega t}-e^{-j\omega t})$$

The continuous Fourier transform of your signal has two spectral lines with an amplitude of $1$ each, and that is what you will (roughly) get from the DFT if you use a forward scaling of $1/N$.

Spectral leakage. A direct consequence of the DFT definition is, that the signal is periodic in both domains with the DFT length $N$, i.e. $x[n] = x[n+mN], X[k] = X[k+mN], m \in \mathbb{Z}$. If you repeat your signal after N points you can see that its not a sine wave anymore and there is a discontinuity at the repetition point. You only get a single line with the DFT if the DFT window contains an integer number of periods.

In other words: the DFT calculates the spectrum at $N$ discrete frequencies. If the frequency of your signal is not one of the grid frequencies the energy needs to be distributed over the neighboring values. The frequency of your signal is $\omega = \frac{1}{2\pi} Hz$ and your frequency grid has a resolution of $\Delta f = \frac{299}{200 \cdot 300} Hz$